# Why I can't load this image?

Tags: c#, image, system.drawing

I am going crazy trying to retrieve a jpg image in C#

This is my class:

```
namespace PdfReport
{
    // Classe base che rappresenta un PDF:
    public class iTextDocumentBase : MyManagerCSharp.ManagerDB
    {
        // Oggetto MemoryStream che contiene il PDF:
        protected System.IO.MemoryStream _risultatoMemoryStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();

        protected iTextSharp.text.Document _document;   // Generico documento di iText valido per qualsiasi formato di output
        protected iTextSharp.text.Chapter _capitolo;    // Contenitore per un insieme di Section opportunamente sequenziate
        protected iTextSharp.text.Section _section;     // Parte del Document costituita da un insieme di Paragraph opportunamente disposti

        protected System.Drawing.Image _backgroundImg = System.Drawing.Image.(Server.MapPath("~/Path/Relative/To/Root.jpg"));

        ..........................................................
        ..........................................................
        ..........................................................
}
```

As you can see I am trying to obtain the image by this line:

```
protected System.Drawing.Image _backgroundImg = System.Drawing.Image.(Server.MapPath("~/Path/Relative/To/Root.jpg"));
```

The problem is that I obtain the following errors message:

> ```
> Error 78  The name 'Server' does not exist in the current context C:\Develop\EarlyWarning\public\Implementazione\Ver2\PdfReport\iTextDocumentBase.cs  43  79  PdfReport
> Error 77  Identifier expected C:\Develop\EarlyWarning\public\Implementazione\Ver2\PdfReport\iTextDocumentBase.cs  43  78  PdfReport
> ```

Why? What can I do to solve?

Answer (score 0):

This issue seems to have nothing to do with images. First of all, this is not valid C# syntax:

```
System.Drawing.Image.(Server.MapPath("~/Path/Relative/To/Root.jpg"));
```

You can't just put a `(` after a `.`. You need to give a method name there (probably `FromFile` in this case).

As for the "The name 'Server' does not exist in the current context" error, this is happening because you are either missing the assembly reference or `using` statement for the `Server` class. `Server.MapPath()` is a method that's intended for ASP.NET projects. Are you working on an ASP.NET project?